# JDG on OpenShift Online - HotRodClientException despite proper permissions assigned to roles

Tags: datagrid, openshift, redhat, infinispan

I deployed JDG on OpenShift Online with the following 
- Image stream "jboss-datagrid71-openshift-rhel7.json" v1.2
- username 'admin' with role 'admin' and '___schema_manager'
- And given the permissions of READ, WRITE, EXEC, ADMIN, ALL for both the roles. Tried with just 'ALL' also.
- **Refer images, Config-env-vars.png and Cache-env-vars.png within the Info.zip  for the environment configurations done**. (Available @ https://drive.google.com/file/d/12EWF1AUB4d60mP_gmTkN4Qlh2pzzv6xi/view?usp=sharing)

While deploying client-side Java application (basically Hotrod with security enabled and with Protobuf based query feature), we are getting the following exception. **Attached the logs from the DataGrid server and client application pods**

```
Caused by: org.infinispan.client.hotrod.exceptions.HotRodClientException: java.lang.SecurityException: ISPN000287: Unauthorized access: subject 'Subject with principal(s): [SimpleUserPrincipal [name=admin], InetAddressPrincipal [address=10.131.14.124/10.131.14.124], admin@ApplicationRealm, admin@ApplicationRealm, ___schema_manager@ApplicationRealm, admin, ___schema_manager]' lacks 'WRITE' permission
```

FYI,

I use the following version of Infinispan from redhat repository

```
<version.org.infinispan>8.4.2.Final-redhat-1</version.org.infinispan>
```

In Java, while creating a Configuration Builder, I did in this way. Full code is available @ https://github.com/techtantric/JDG-Remote-Hotrod-Secured

```
ConfigurationBuilder builder = new ConfigurationBuilder();
          builder.addServer()
                .host(host)
                .port(hotrodPort).security().authentication().serverName("jdg-server").saslMechanism("DIGEST-MD5").callbackHandler(new LoginHandler("admin", "password".toCharArray(), "ApplicationRealm")).enable()
                .marshaller(new ProtoStreamMarshaller());  // The Protobuf based marshaller is required for query capabilities
          cacheManager = new RemoteCacheManager(builder.build());
```

---

Please help us resolving this issue. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You should not be touching the ___schema_manager role.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, Tristan.  I have given ___schema_manager role to the user after seeing the issue resolution here. https://issues.jboss.org/browse/JDG-508. Moreover, the same code is working fine in my local. Only in Openshift environment, I could see this issue. The Microservices code that I use can be viewed @ https://github.com/techtantric/JDG-Remote-Hotrod-Secured.

Comment: Uploaded the zip file in the drive. Please help. Thanks. https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1doBo4jUPsbXK0bDPmNWUknkOc7GgQBxX?usp=sharing

Comment: The issue seems to be with the documentation which refers to a CONTAINER_SECURITY_IDENTITY_ROLE_MAPPER config var instead of the correct CONTAINER_SECURITY_ROLE_MAPPER. Because of this the `identity-role-mapper` was not being applied and the user roles were not being identified correctly.

Comment: Thanks Tristan. It worked. Documentation misled this. Kudos to you for your patience and help.